# One-time purchase iTunes album?

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

I've been trying to download some WOODKID to my iTunes library.

I don't see how to do this: looks like I need to subscribe to Apple Music?

Is one-time purchase no longer possible?

How am I meant to download a music album to my phone so that I can play it offline nowadays?

Comment: Are you choosing to use iOS to complete the purchase? To answer your three questions, no, no, we can only guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good here ([iTunes Store app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/itunes-store/id915061235) on iOS 13):

[image]

Comment: Great answer. My guess is OP is using the music app instead of the store app, we will have to wait for them to document what they're doing or have someone look over their shoulder and take notes.

Comment: Yeah I had no idea iTunes Store was its own app that I had to download (guess I deleted it?) from the App Store. Would be more convenient if the music app bundled this.

Comment: @theonlygusti I'm actually glad the Store is a different app, buying and listening isn't the same thing (especially for people who don't buy there music from Apple :-))